# Convertir xls en xlsx Visual studio 2008

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008

Necesito saber como puedo convertir xml a xmls, tengo un problema al abrir los ficheros de excel y la única solución que encuentro es cambiar el formato y así que me lo habrán las nuevas versiones de Excel.

Podéis ayudarme?
No sé si tengo que instalar algun tool, voy algo perdida con el visual studio 2008 ya que no veo que se puedan instalar paquetes y toda la información que encuentro es instalando paquetes.

Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo usar la herramienta [Koogra](https://sourceforge.net/projects/koogra/)

Tienes más información en http://basaratali.blogspot.com/2010/05/reading-xls-and-xlsx-files-from-net.html

Otra opción es usar excel interop u otra librería externa, por ejemplo Free Spire.XLS el cual puedes obtener de NuGet para convertir xls a xlsx.

```
Workbook workbook = new Workbook();
Workbook.LoadFromFile("Input.xls");
Workbook.SaveToFile("Output.xlsx", ExcelVersion.Version2013);
```

Comment: el problema es que uso visual studio 2008 que no acepta librerias externas, por eso no puedo usar Nuget ni tampoco Koogra.